# How can I find who or which process sent signals to my process on Solaris

Tags: unix, solaris, signals

I have JBoss running on Sun Java 1.5.
From time to time, it unexpectedly shuts down (in orderly fashion).
I suspect some other process is sending it kill or CTRL+C signals.

Is there a way on Unix/Solaris to trace who sent the signal?

Comment: Note that the JBoss process cannot shut down in an orderly fashion if some authorized process sends a SIGKILL signal; there is no second chance for that signal.  Although a process can find out some information about which process sent it a catchable signal, only the receiving process can do that in the ordinary course of events.  There isn't a way for an outside auditing program to find out which other process sent a signal to JBoss _after_ JBoss has died.  You may be able to use `dtrace` to track whodunnit if you are running it before the death occurs; afterwards, the information is lost.

Answer (score 7):

On Solaris, you can use a simple dtrace script to find who is killing your process (assuming its name is `java`, adjust it otherwise):

```
dtrace -qn '
proc:::signal-send
/ args[1]->pr_fname == "java" /
{
        printf("Process %d (%s by UID %d) sending signal %d to java (pid=%d)\n",
        pid,execname,uid,arg1,args[1]->pr_pid);
}'
```

Comment: I assume this must be running in parallel with my java process?

Comment: Yes, this script need to be running to trace the signals.

Comment: See also `/usr/demo/dtrace/sig.d` on a Solaris machine - this script is a demo from the DTrace user's guide.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sigaction` to determine the source of the signal. pid may be zero as the signal was send from the kernel or via some user interaction (pressing ctrl+c)

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void signal_handler(int sig, siginfo_t *info, void *data) {

    printf ("signal: [%d], pid: [%d], uid: [%d]\n", sig,
            info->si_pid,
            info->si_uid );
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    struct sigaction sa;
    memset ( &sa, '\0', sizeof ( struct sigaction ) );

    sa.sa_sigaction = &signal_handler;
    sa.sa_flags |= SA_SIGINFO;

    sigemptyset ( &sa.sa_mask );

    sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGTERM, &sa, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGQUIT, &sa, NULL);

    while ( 1 ) {
        sleep (1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @erezul: No; sadly, the program can't investigate the past.  There is no post-mortem mechanism available to find which process sent the signal to the JBoss process.  You might be able to wrap the JBoss code so that it gets to report the signal sender, but it probably requires more major work than that.

Comment: C code isn't particularly easy to plug into a Java based application server. Moreover, the way you use it would override the default JVM handlers which might be an issue too. Finally, as already stated, sigkill won't be caught by sigaction.